# Как получить по ID даный элемент из базы?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

есть такая схема для колекции ресторанов

```
const PointSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
})

const RestaurantSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    require: true
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    default: ""
  },
  image: {
    type: String,
  },
  rating: {
    type: String
  },
  sale: {
    type: String,
  },
  time: {
    type: String
  },
  minPrice: {
    type: String,
  },
  priceRange: {
    type: String
  },
  categories: [],
  points: [PointSchema]
})
```

Исходя из этого получаем такую структуру в Mongo
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А разве не так это должно делаться?

```
const RestaurantSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    require: true
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    default: ""
  },
  image: {
    type: String,
  },
  rating: {
    type: String
  },
  sale: {
    type: String,
  },
  time: {
    type: String
  },
  minPrice: {
    type: String,
  },
  priceRange: {
    type: String
  },
  categories: [],
  points: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Point'}]
})
```

Чтоб при запросе `find` делать вот так:

```
RestaurantModel.find({}).populate("points")
```

Тем самым получать не id элемента, а полную информацию

Answer (score 0):

```
const Restaurant = mongoose.model('Restaurant', RestaurantSchema);


Restaurant.find({_id: '1234567890'}).then(console.log);
// или
Restaurant.findById('1234567890').then(console.log);
```

В `mongoose.model` передается 2 аргумента: название коллекции (с добавлением `s` в конце) и раннее созданную schema. Я не знаю название вашей коллекции, так что это привел как пример.

Настоятельно рекомендую вам прочитать [документацию](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) по mongoose, дабы в дальнейшем у вас возникало меньше подобных вопросов.