# Как сделать запрос по ид сразу для 5 элементов?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

есть объект ресторана где в **field kinds** я указываю **Id** которая ссылается на колекцию kinds
Исходя из того что я знаю ID и колекцию я могу получить и сам объект по Id , однако у меня массив из IDшников. Исходя из этого мне надо отправить запрос несколько раз, с разным ID и значения записывать в стейт. Учитывая что один ресторан может иметь хоть 20-30 категорий , делать по 20-30 запросов лишь для того что бы получить информацию о категории не совсем правильно. Какой способ в данном случае можно использовать что бы ограничиться лишь одним запросом?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Тут не вполне понятно, что именно требуется. Если уже есть массив `id`, и надо для него получить все объекты, то это используйте `$in`. Если надо при получении объекта сразу получить и обьекты категорий, на которые он ссылается, то используйте агрегацию, а именно оператор `$unwind`.

Comment: Я в прошлом вашем вопросе, написал, что есть [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) который "джойнит" эти id, и все вытаскивается одним запросом.

Answer (score 0):

Если модель записана вот так:

```
  kinds: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Kinds'}]
```

то вот так

```
Model.find({}).populate("kinds")
```

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1263776/271026

Comment: У меня модель записана как  "Kind" но в базе данных она делает колекцию kinds

Comment: в таком случае в ref пиши 'Kind'